# How order by with union in sql each select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

each select statement order works well,

but when I union both, it doesn't order result well

how can I order in this query?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NM, DEP_CD, 2 AS POSITION FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' 
and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0 ORDER BY NM 
DESC)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NM, DEP_CD, 1 AS POSITION FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110' 
ORDER BY NM DESC)
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: What did you expect? That the outer ORDER BY will order by POSITION desc, and then within each branch of UNION ALL, that the order by NM desc will be preserved? That is not how it works. It makes no sense to ORDER each member of the union; instead, use a single ORDER BY, at the end - `ORDER BY POSITION DESC, NM DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only guaranteed order is the *last* one you ask for. If you want to order by `3 DESC` and then `NM DESC`, you have to specify `ORDER BY 3 DESC, NM DESC` at the end of your query.

You can't order by `NM DESC` in the inline view and then order by `3 DESC` in the outer query and expect the `NM DESC` ordering to be preserved. For performance reasons, SQL queries are not necessarily executed in the same sequence they are written; when rows flow from one step of the query to another the ordering may not be preserved.

Beware of tricks that may appear to return the correct order without specifying it. There are some operations that return rows in a preserved order, but you do not want your results to depend on the internal operations chosen by the optimizer. For example, if your `UNION` uses a `SORT GROUP BY` the results may look fine. But tomorrow, if the optimizer decides that `HASH GROUP BY` is fater, the results may be different.

If you want deterministic results you must fully specify the `ORDER BY` at the end.

Comment: Is there any way that I can order for the first select statement?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` for a `UNION` statement applies to the combined both sets, not just the first or second one. Just put all the columns you want in the last order and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in one more table:

```
select * from (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NM, DEP_CD, 2 AS POSITION FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0 ORDER BY NM DESC)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NM, DEP_CD, 1 AS POSITION FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110' ORDER BY NM DESC)

) ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT from the result created (inner_table) and sort accordingly

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NM, DEP_CD, 2 AS POSITION FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0 ORDER BY NM DESC)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NM, DEP_CD, 1 AS POSITION FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110' ORDER BY NM DESC)
) AS inner_table
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```